# Code optimisation for finding false co-ordinates from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, optimization

I have a csv file containing co-ordinates of trees (x & y)  and Tree diameters. I have to find out false trees. My approach is I find the Euclidean distance b/w the co-ordinates as “e”.

Then I calculate the the distance b/w the trees by subtracting the sum of radii of 2 trees from the Euclidean distance i.e  “d=e-(r1+r2). If the distance is less than 0.5 then it is considered as false tree.

I have checked it on multiple files & this works perfectly fine.

Now the problem is that the csv contains approximately 50k trees and I am using 2 for loops, so I need to optimise the code, is there a better approach for it. Or some other way maybe to optimise the code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.